# bluescale magento theme footer_links block

Tags: magento

When I edit static block in magento (ver 1.6.2.0) admin for bluescale footer_links block, then an error message appears like ”A block identifier with the same properties already exists in the selected store.”

How do I correct this error? Please help!

Shaman

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a Static Block with the id `footer_links` for the selected store view.

You can only have one per store.  Double-check the list of Static Blocks.